# The following _TypeError was thrown building MyBrick: type 'int' is not a subtype of type 'double'

Tags: flutter, integer, double

I'm coding a flutter video game here.I have tried to test it on the web and it worked fine but when doing it on my physical device(phone) an error encountered on brick.dart file.

As a beginner I would like to get help from you guys:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyBrick extends StatelessWidget {
  final x;
  final y;

  MyBrick({this.x, this.y});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment(x, y),
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 20,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The flutter `Alignment(double x, double y)` widget takes doubles. Since you are passing `x` and `y` to your widget without specifying their types, if you pass the values `x = 1` and `y = 3` this alignment widget will throw that error. Update your code to include your field types. this will force you to pass `x` and `y` of appropriate types or you will get a linter error:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class MyBrick extends StatelessWidget {
  final double x; // type your fields
  final double y; // type your fields

  MyBrick({this.x, this.y});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      alignment: Alignment(x, y), // accepts only doubles so if you pass an int value, you will get that error
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
        child: Container(
          color: Colors.white,
          height: 20,
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width / 5,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir for your help,I really appreciate it!!!!

Comment: You're most welcome. Please, mark this question as solved to let other now ;)

Answer (score 0):

because **Alignment** widget expects double values but you're passing int values.

```
alignment: Alignment(x.toDouble(), y.toDouble()), // convert int to double
```